# What is the most appropriate test to determine relationship for these 2 variables?

Tags: correlation

I want to look at the relationship between 1 response (1-5 likert scale) and a dichotomous outcome variable (here/not here).  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Kruskal-Wallis Rank Sum Test. 
SO that you can check whether the dichotomous outcome variable is associate with the response. 
As the Kruskal-Wallis Rank Sum Test does not assume normal distribution, it fit the likert scale quite well.
Nonetheless, if you strongly believe the scale is evenly spaced and normally distributed, a simple t-test can be used.

Answer (score 0):

research logit and probit.  They fall into the category of "limited dependent" approaches, and are often used when you have an independent variable and want to develop a statistically based model that gives you a yes/no outcome